# statement to skip empty data frames in a function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a function similar to this in `R`, which uses a `df` as main argument. However, the df could be empty and I would like to skip those if I run the function using `lapply`
e.g `lapply(FileNames, function(y) my.function(y))`

my function looks like this

```
my.function <- function(table) {
file <- read.csv(table, header=T)

  if(nrow(table) == 0) 
   {next}

#skip the df if is empty and stop processing that df
#do more stuffs if not empty
}
```

I've tried this so far but if the data frame is empty the whole process crashes, any tip?

Comment: Instead of `next` you could use `return`, perhaps `return(NULL)`, depending on how your function is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of data frames like this:

```r
my_list <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3),
                data.frame(a = c(), b = c()),
                data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))

my_list
#> [[1]]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
#> 5 5 5
```

Then your function could be something like this:

```
my_func <- function(df) {

  # return NULL and stop function if dataframe has zero rows
  if(nrow(df) == 0) return(NULL)

  # Do work on dataframes with one or more rows
  data.frame(sum = df$a + df$b)
}
```

So now if we `lapply` we get:

```r
result <- lapply(my_list, my_func)

result
#> [[1]]
#>   sum
#> 1   2
#> 2   4
#> 3   6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   sum
#> 1   2
#> 2   4
#> 3   6
#> 4   8
#> 5  10
```

And if you want to remove the `NULL` values from your list, you can do:

```r
result[!sapply(result, is.null)]
#> [[1]]
#>   sum
#> 1   2
#> 2   4
#> 3   6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   sum
#> 1   2
#> 2   4
#> 3   6
#> 4   8
#> 5  10
```

---

**Update**

To include a warning message in the function if it comes across an empty file, we can do:

```r
my_func <- function(df) {
  
  # return NULL and stop function if dataframe has zero rows
  if(nrow(df) == 0) {
    warning("This file is empty")
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  # Do work on dataframes with one or more rows
  data.frame(sum = df$a + df$b)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: and what about if I want to skip it but also write a txt saying "this file is empty"? Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "write a txt"? Write it where? Do you want there to be a text string in your list saying "this file is empty", or do you want a warning message printed to the console?